# Как правильно вывести на PHP или же как создать страницу динамически

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте!

Как на PHP вывести на страницу некоторую информацию из БД?

К примеру:

```
<div class="main">
        <h1>Статьи</h1><br>
        <?php
         $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','12345');
              mysql_select_db('algoritm_db',$connect);
              $sql="select * from articles";
              $result=mysql_query($sql)or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
              $i=0;
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) 
              {
                print "<div class='zaglav'>".$row[1]."</div>";
                $i=$i+1;
              }
        ?>

</div>
```

Т.е я хотел создать несколько блоков div одного класса, но с разной инф.. но не получается, выводит код PHP и все.... Выводит после print...

Что я делаю не так?

Спасибо.

Comment: Файл с каким расширением?

Хостинг с php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробую еще так:

```
mysql_select_db('algoritm_db',$connect);
              $sql="SELECT * FROM articles";
              $result=mysql_query($sql)or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());;
              $i=0;
              if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
              }
              else
              {
                  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
                  {
        ?>   
                            <div class="zaglav"><?php print $row['caption']?></div>
                            <div class="article" id="article<?php print $i?>"><br>
                            <?php print $row['value']?>
                            <br><br>
                            <a href="#" class="btnAr" id="butAr<?php print $i?>">Скрыть</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="preview" id="preview<?php print $i?>">
                            <br><?php print $row['value_preview']?>
                            <br><br>
                            <a href="#" class="btnAr" id="butAr<?php print $i?>">Подробнее...</a>
                            <div>
        <?php
                       $i=$i+1;
                      }
              }
              mysql_free_result($result);
        ?>
```

Теперь заработало)) Ура!!)

Судя по содержанию сайта [Правила оформления программного кода](http://yukosh.ru/library/rules/) первый вариант вообще в топку надо выбросить!!! Учимся на ошибках)

Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

во первых, где ";" в конце подобных строк?

```
print "<div class='zaglav'>$row[1]</div>"
```

да и переменные желательно выделять, вот как нужно это делать:

```
print "<div class='zaglav'>".$row[1]."</div>";
```

это касается и переменной $i которую вы выводите в цикле

в правилах хорошего тона, запрос к БД принято оформлять в таком виде, так более легче воспринимается визуально:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM `articles`";
```

а так же, если в БД не будет записей, данный код выведет ошибку SQL (если включен показ ошибок), так что перед выводом из БД, проверяйте количество записей.

Comment: А так-же - если бы **работал интерпритатор** - код бы не выводился...

Comment: хмм, перечитал его вопрос, точно, я думал у него в коде ошибки, хотя они там явно есть, я их указал :D

Comment: про ; эт мой косяк забыл... но все равно выводит код Php... дело в цикле... а именно что-то с print...

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгяд ещё проще можно!

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
    printf("<div class="zaglav">%s</div>
    <div class="article" id="article">%s<br>",$row['caption'],$row['stroka2']);
}
```

printf - удобней мне кажется при таких выводах!

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я помню HTML-разметка, встроенная в PHP-скрипт обычно выводилась в echo:

```
echo "<title>".$title."</title>";
```

Или это у меня от фреймворков такая привычка. :)